# How to check exception cause using pytest raises?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pytest

I'd like to test that an exception is raised from another exception type.

```
import pytest


def throw_with_cause():
  raise Exception("Failed") from ValueError("That was unexpected.")
 
with pytest.raises(Exception): # from ValueError???
  throw_with_cause()
```

I'm surprised not to see a way to inspect the exception chain in the pytest raises docs.  https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-raises

Is there a clean way to do this using ptyest raises?

Comment: I think you are out of luck here - this information is not contained in the exception info (nor in the exception itself where you to check it).

Comment: Thanks for looking!  Something gross I could do is skip pytest raises, catch the exception, and then inspect __ cause __.  So I think it's possible.  I'd rather stay closer to our convention of using pytest raises if I can though.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about that. If you really need it, you can write your own check function, but I agree that it is generally better to stick to the standard methods.

Comment: Oh, I can get the exception with excinfo.value.  It's not awesome, but I'll probably assert on that.

Comment: Ah, ok - so you can answer this yourself, and I learned something :)

Comment: Thanks for rubber ducking, MrBean Bremen!  I wouldn't have gotten there without the banter.

Comment: Are you in medical imaging?  I've been out for a few years, but pydicom looks handy!

Comment: Yep, that often helps :) And yes, I'm in medical imaging, and contribute to pydicom because I like it, too.

Answer (score 7):

Until something more readable comes along, I'm doing the following.

```
import pytest

def throw_with_cause():
   raise Exception("Failed") from ValueError("That was unexpected.")


def test_throws_with_cause():
    with pytest.raises(Exception, match="Failed") as exc_info:
        throw_with_cause()
    assert type(exc_info.value.__cause__) is ValueError
```

Comment: I would suggest using `isinstance(exc_info.value.__cause__, ValueError)` instead of type.